# How to trigger an action the moment a specific statement validates true?

Tags: xcode, if-statement, timer, triggers

In Xcode you can check when you hit a button, wether an integer is 9 (go to that page) or 7 (go to an other page). Is there a way to automatically trigger an action when the number becomes 60 for example? I know you can do this with a timer, that checks every second if the `if` statment is `true`. But is there an other way to achieve the same?

Comment: I believe somebody (you?) posted the exact same question a few days ago.  That question generated quite a few negative responces, because the poster couldn't explain what this number was or how it was incremented.  These same problems still stand.  Where is this number coming from?  How is it incremented?  Why can't it be tested at the point of being incremented?

Answer (score 0):

Most debuggers can watch a memory location and break the application when the content of that location changes. So if you want to find out *why* and *where* something changes, that's your way. If you want the user interface to respond to that change during normal (i.e. non-debug) operations, then you'd better add some code to the location where things change, to pass that event along.